# S3サーバーから取得したファイルを結合したい

Tags: php, aws, laravel, amazon-s3

S3サーバーから取得したファイルとアップロードしたファイルを結合したいと考えて
下記のコードを作成いたしました。

```
public function uploadJoin(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $content = \Storage::disk('s3')->get( $file_name );
    
    $data = file_get_contents( $content );
    $data .= file_get_contents( $file );
    
    \Storage::disk('s3')->put( $file_name, $data );
    
    return [
        'message' => 'ok',
    ];
}
```

しかしファイル結合「file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path」とエラーが出て結合できていない状態です。
S3サーバーから取得したファイルをバイナリデータとして扱うにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「うまくいかない」とは具体的にどういった状況なのか、またファイル形式などの情報もないと詳しい回答が付きづらいと思います。 / また、"ファイルの結合" に焦点を絞れば、"S3から取得した" は省いたコードにした方が問題がシンプルになるんじゃないかと。

Comment: こちら「file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path」とエラーが出ております。

Comment: file_get_contents の使い方を今一度確認してみてください。引数には URL またはファイルのパスが渡されるべきですが、あなたのコードではファイルの内容が直接渡されている気がします。

Answer (score 0):

エラーを直訳すると、file_get_contents()の第一パラメータに有効なパスを指定しろって感じなので、単純にfile_get_contents()のパラメータが間違っているんだと思いますが。
関数の仕様は確認されたのでしょうか？
[PHP: file_get_contents - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

getメソッドの返り値を見てみましょう。

```
public function get($path, $lock = false)
{
    if ($this->isFile($path)) {
        return $lock ? $this->sharedGet($path) : file_get_contents($path);
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$path}.");
}
```

[Filesystem.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fe6e25e697e5fbf3cfdf6a1826dc0078d7bce822/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L51)

`$lock`が、`true`なら`sharedGetメソッド`、`false`なら`file_get_contents関数`の返り値を返していることがわかります。

`$lock`は規定値が`false`のため、今回の場合は、`file_get_contents関数`の返り値が、ご提示のコードの`$content`に代入されます。

つまりどう言うことか？
`getメソッド`の返り値は、**第一引数のファイルの中身**なので、`file_get_contents関数`に入れると、「そんなファイルないよ！」と言うエラーになる。